# How to set argument optional in Graphql?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

In my mongodb model, name is required but i want to make it optional in graphql. How can i do this?

```
    updateExercise: {
            type: ExerciseType,
            args: {
                id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                username: {type: new GraphQLString},
                description: {type: new GraphQLString},
                duration: {type: new GraphQLInt},
                date: {type: new GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                Exercise.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id)
                .then(exercise => {
                    exercise.username = args.username,
                    exercise.description = args.description,
                    exercise.duration = args.duration,
                    exercise.date = args.date
                    exercise.save()
                    .then( () => 'Succesfully Updated')
                    .catch( e => console.log(e) )
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `findByIdAndUpdate` function. It should probably be used in this way:

```js
const SomeType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    updateExercise: {
            type: ExerciseType,
            args: {
                id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                username: {type: GraphQLString},
                description: {type: GraphQLString},
                duration: {type: GraphQLInt},
                date: {type: GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Exercise.findByIdAndUpdate(args.id, {
                    username: args.username || undefined,
                    description: args.description,
                    duration: args.duration,
                    date: args.date
                }).then(() => 'Succesfully Updated')
                  .catch(e => console.log(e))
            })
        }
    }
});
```

We use a little trick in JS to short-circuit the returned value. This will supply `undefined` for the username property when `args.username` is `null`. If you are in an environment where you are not sure if `undefined` as been reassigned you can use `void 0` instead. If you are using a new TypeScript or EcmaScript version you can use the newer `??` operator instead of `||`.